# Connect to an action in a namespaced controller that isn't a collection or member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to have a url like this:

/admin/providers/connect

that a 3rd party can post to.  It isn't a restful resource.  Its just a url.  I'd like it to map to the connect method in my providers controller in the admin namespace.

How can i do that?

here is what i have:

```
  namespace :admin do
    get '/admin/providers/connect', to: 'providers#connect'
  end
```

which is just redirecting to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must have some login checking in before filter. You need to skip that before filter in your provider_controller.
lets say you have check_login before filter which redirects to dashboard for some reason

```
skip_before_filter :check_login
```